# What is this plant? Is it edible? Poisonous? Thank you

Tags: identification, vegetables, weeds

I was in my garden when I noticed a weed that I’d never seen before. I looked on the internet and maybe it’s a nightshade??? The inside of the fruit had lots of tiny seeds that reminded me of pomegranate seeds. It has white flowers with five points that are yellow on the inside. Anyway, I hope someone can identify it. Thanks.[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, as Bamboo said, black nightshade (not to be confused with deadly nightshade) is a likely candidate (but there are other possibilities); definitely looks like a Solanaceae plant. They look a lot like wonderberries, too, except the calyxes are bigger. Let me know if you want wonderberry seeds for something that is definitely edible when ripe (I saved loads of them, this year); you can do that on my website link since there's no private messaging here. Wonderberry plants smell a lot like gourd plants (Lagenaria siceraria).

Answer (score 2):

It might be Solanum nigrum, common name black nightshade, though the  single leaf you show looks a little narrow. Anecdotally, it is thought to be highly toxic, but how poisonous it actually is is not entirely clear, see here https://pfaf.org/user/plant.aspx?LatinName=Solanum+nigrum. It is neither woody nightshade (Solanum dulcamara) nor deadly nightshade (Atropa belladonna), both of which are toxic; of the two, Atropa is the most toxic.